# SFDX CLI is not working for any commands

Tags: salesforcedx, salesforcedx-cli, vs-code

SFDX suddenly stopped working for any commands. I updated sfdx and its plugins, still its giving same error. I am using same from VS Code, I created scratch org and performed few activities, and after some time it is giving me below error. Tried with packaging commands, VS Code extensions, nothing seems to be working fine.

```
sfdx force:org:open -u Alias
(node:85908) UnexpectedValueTypeError Plugin: sfdx-cli: Value is not defined
module: @oclif/config@1.15.1
task: runHook prerun
plugin: sfdx-cli
root: C:\Users\UserName\AppData\Local\sfdx\client\7.66.2-4f159a1d07
See more details with DEBUG=*
ERROR running force:org:open:  Value is not defined
```

**SFDX cli version**

```
sfdx-cli/7.66.2-4f159a1d07 win32-x64 node-v12.13.0
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was happened because, `sfdx-config.json` was corrupted(with wrong values).

Ref - https://github.com/forcedotcom/cli/issues/516